# Listening to the Collection creation only one time in Firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a boolean field which is set to true once a specific collection in the firestore is created, how can I listen to the creation of that collection, so that the field is set to true, I tried to use onCreate() listener, but the function is executed everytime a new document is created in the collection, I want to listen for just one time, once it's created no more listening

Comment: Do not create random collections it is a bad practice. Every thing starts with collection then you have documents and those document can have collections and so one...

Comment: To create any collection you need to save there at least one document if you delete this document collection will gone. And you have no way tho know on client side what collection doc have unless you make bunch of functions with firebase-admin SDK but this is only wasting resources. If there is any function which can listen to all collections.

Comment: I have a Collection called Customers, and then SubCollection called Projects, in each document in Projects, there is a flag called hasDataSet, which indicates whether the project has dataSet or not. The customer can upload data such as images to the project, and each data ,uploaded by the user, a new document is created for it in the project => {projectDoc} => dataset => {dataSetDoc}, so I need to set the hasDataSet flag to true once the dataset Collection is created, how can I do that ?

Comment: You no need any flags. Just make an request to specific path and if there won't be any documents you will know there are no documents.

Comment: Or if you really need you can make firebase function and listen `onCreate()` `onDelete()` events in specific collection path and for example count documents in collection.

Comment: but, won't that be a bad practice(performance, price) to listen to each document creation, where I just want to listen only for the collection creation?

Comment: I can explain it to you but i cannot understand it for you.

Answer (score 1):

A collection is automatically created when the first document is written to it, and automatically deleted when the last document is removed. There is no event that you can listen to for collection creation.

As Mises commented, wanting this typically indicates a flaw in your data model, as it's best to have well-known names for your collections (e.g. `posts`, `users`). Collections names typically match constant/hard-coded values in your code, while document names often end up as variables that you dynamically populate when reading from the collections.

Comment: Hi Frank, I have a Collection called Customers, and then SubCollection called Projects, in each document in Projects, there is a flag called hasDataSet, which indicates whether the project has dataSet or not. The customer can upload data such as images to the project, and each data ,uploaded by the user, a new document is created for it in the project => {projectDoc} => dataset => {dataSetDoc}, so I need to set the hasDataSet flag to true once the dataset Collection is created, how can I do that ?

Comment: In other words, I need to listen to just one document creation, once one document is created, it's over, is there a way for doing so ?

Comment: It seems like setting the `hasDataSet` field is idempotent, meaning that you could do it every time you write a document in the subcollection without harm.